# PHP Parse Error: Syntax Error; unexpected end of file

Tags: php, parse-error

trying to setup the webpage with this PHP. I first got the blank page, then had it display the error(s) which was an internal server error. After a bit of research I saw that it's mostly the code that causes issues. If anyone would be kind enough to look this through for any possible solutions, I'd appreciate it. There is some more html code before this although it does not include any of the PHP.

```
    <?php
$subjectPrefix = 'Site Contact Request';
$emailTo = '***@****.com';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name     = stripslashes(trim($_POST['form-name']));
    $email    = stripslashes(trim($_POST['form-email']));
    $tel      = stripslashes(trim($_POST['form-tel']));
    $assunto  = stripslashes(trim($_POST['form-assunto']));
    $mensagem = stripslashes(trim($_POST['form-mensagem']));
    $pattern  = '/[\r\n]|Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $name) || preg_match($pattern, $email) || preg_match($pattern, $assunto)) {
        die("Header injection detected");
    }
    $emailIsValid = preg_match('/^[^0-9][A-z0-9._%+-]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/', $email);
    if($name && $email && $emailIsValid && $assunto && $mensagem){
        $subject = "$subjectPrefix";
        $body = "Name: $name <br /> Subject: $assunto <br /> Email Address: $email <br /> Telephone Number: $tel <br /> Message: $mensagem";
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.1' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "From: $name <$email>" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Return-Path: $emailTo" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    } else {
        $hasError = true;
    }
}
?>

    <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent): ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your message has been sent.</div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if(isset($hasError) && $hasError): ?>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">An error occurred. Please try later.</div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" id="contact-form" class="comment_form" role="form" method="post">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-name" name="form-name" placeholder="Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="form-email" name="form-email" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="form-tel" name="form-tel" placeholder="Telephone (Optional)">
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-assunto" name="form-assunto" placeholder="Subject" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span8">
                <textarea id="form-mensagem" name="form-mensagem" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="li_paperplane"></i>Send message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: If you already tried `error_reporting(-1);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` and got an "Internal Server Error", and not a PHP error, then you probably have either a permissions or ownership issue with your php file....

Comment: You are missing the `endif;` from `<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent): ?>`/`<?php else: ?>`

Comment: @Sean you're right, good catch.  2 if's and only one endif.

Comment: Please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing one if condition at starting, please modify it like this:-

```
<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent): ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your message has been sent.</div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if(isset($hasError) && $hasError): ?>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">An error occurred. Please try later.</div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?> // this is missing and based on your functionality you can move it to anywhere else
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/74n8d3

Note:- this is very first html started with if condition. depend on your functionality you need to adjust it whereever you want.